# TextBlob and NLTK POS tagging accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, textblob

So far, I have this code below

```py
from textblob import TextBlob
class BrinBot:

    def __init__(self, message): #Accepts the message from the user as the argument
        parse(message)

class parse:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        blob = TextBlob(self.message)
        print(blob.tags)

BrinBot("Handsome Bob's dog is a beautiful Chihuahua")
```

This is the output:

```py
[('Handsome', 'NNP'), ('Bob', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('Chihuahua', 'NNP')]
```

My question is that apparently TextBlob thinks "Handsome" is a singular proper noun, which is not correct as "Handsome" is supposed to be an adjective. Is there a way to fix that, I tried this on NLTK also but got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the capitalization of Handsome is causing it to be treated as part of Bob's name. This is not necessarily an incorrect analyis, but if you want to force an adjectival analysis, you can remove the capitalization of 'handsome' as in text2 and text4 below.

```
text = "Handsome Bob's dog is a beautiful chihuahua"

BrinBot(text)
[('Handsome', 'NNP'), ('Bob', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('Chihuahua', 'NNP')]

text2 = "handsome bob's dog is a beautiful chihuahua"

BrinBot(text2)
[('handsome', 'JJ'), ('bob', 'NN'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('chihuahua', 'NN')]

text3 = "That beautiful chihuahua is handsome Bob's dog"

BrinBot(text3)
[('That', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('chihuahua', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('handsome', 'JJ'), ('Bob', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('dog', 'NN')]

text4 = "That beautiful chihuahua is Handsome Bob's dog"

BrinBot(text4)
[('That', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('chihuahua', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('Handsome', 'NNP'), ('Bob', 'NNP'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```